# Broken SSRS Linechart

Tags: reporting-services, linechart

I am creating a line chart in SSRS. The problem is: I need to display all the date range so I set the horizontal axis as Scalar. However, the line chart will not able to connect each data point in the sequential order.

Anybody had similar issues?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to sort the data beforehand in your dateset or try sorting it via the sorting tab in the properties for your respective grouping.